# Determine if $a_n=\frac{\ln^2(n)}{n^{1/2}}$ is convergent by using the properties of limits

Tags: limits

Determine if  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$=$\frac{\ln^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent by using the properties of limits

So I will take the limits of both top and bottom:
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\ln^2(n))=\infty$  and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt{n}= \infty$.

So limit of the fraction should be $1$ but the calculator does not agree with this.

Reattempt:

Derivative of $ln^2(n)$ is $\frac{2\ln(n)}{n}$

Derivative of $\sqrt{n}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Dividing top and bottom gives $\frac{4}{n}$ so limit is 0.

Comment: First your limit is in indeterminate form. Second $\infty/\infty \not=1$

Comment: Do you know L'Hospital rule and indeterminate forms?

Comment: And you mean $n\to \infty$ not $a\to \infty$ right?

Comment: I will give it a go using L'Hopital rule.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule should be forbidden in most cases.

Comment: @Bernard Why is that?

Comment: First it can lead to wrong results if students forget the hypotheses (in particular, the denominator must not be $0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, except at $x_0$ itself). Second, when it works, Taylor's formula at order $1$ works. Third, using equivalents is often more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

For any number $\alpha>0$, we have

$$\log(x) \le \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha}$$

Comment: Super cool. This inequality (for $0 < \alpha < 1/4$) actually provides that the limit vanishes, despite that convergence is relatively slow.

Comment: @StevenHarding Thank you!  And that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It can be easy if you exchange variable n to $ e^{2x} $. Then you can use L'Hospital Rule or just use definition.

Comment: I did it but without a substitution.

Comment: It's all right, because calculate this derivation is easy.